# How can I do case-sensitive global seach in github?

Tags: git, github, search

I want to do a case-sensitive **global** search by code through all GitHub repos? Is there any way to do this?

I tried exact match `"AF_UNIX"` instead of `AF_UNIX`, but it still shows this for example:

```
static void __exit af_unix_exit(void)
```

This very much clogs the output and makes it difficult to search
`'AF_UNIX'` also didn't help, is searches with quotes..

Please help, sorry if it's obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supporting this [is on the GitHub roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/9759#discussioncomment-1929045), but for now, you can use a regex marked as case-sensitive as a [workaround](https://github.com/search?q=%2F%28%3F-i%29AF_UNIX%2F&type=code):

```
/(?-i)AF_UNIX/
```

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax